# Point Doubling (P -> 2P) The Base Point of the Secp256k1 Elliptic Curve

Tags: javascript, cryptography, ethereum, bitcoin, elliptic-curve

as a learning exercise, I am trying to code the first point doubling (Base point P -> 2P) for the Secp256k1 Elliptic Curve.  I am using Javascript, and the ethers package for BigNumber.  Frustratingly, I am running into a problem where the result I am getting for 2P doesn't appear to lie on the curve.  Can someone please help me determine where I am making a mistake?

The coordinates I'm getting as a result are:

```
X: 0xf1b9e9c77c87bf0ac622382b581826898cfc9232e025d86d904bfd33375faf1a
Y: 0x8162c7b446b54638e9181b71770b2d718e6953a360625a02392097c7db09c608
```

Which returns false from my isPointOnCurve() method.  As a sanity check, I checked the base point in the isPointOnCurve() method, and that returns true (thankfully).

Please see my code below:

```
const { ethers, BigNumber } = require('ethers');

//variable initialization found from https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Secp256k1
bigZero = BigNumber.from(0);
bigTwo = BigNumber.from(2);
bigThree = BigNumber.from(3);
ellipticCurveB = BigNumber.from(7);
generatorPrime = BigNumber.from("0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F");
order = BigNumber.from("0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141");
baseXCoord = BigNumber.from("0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798");
baseYCoord = BigNumber.from("0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8");

// slope = ( (3*x^2) * (2*y)^-1 ) mod order
// 2Px = slope^2 - 2*baseXCoord
// 2Py = slope * ( 2Px - baseXCoord ) - baseYCoord

m = (bigThree.mul(baseXCoord.pow(bigTwo)).mul(modinv(bigTwo.mul(baseYCoord), order))).mod(order);
TwoPx = (m.pow(bigTwo).sub(bigTwo.mul(baseXCoord))).mod(order);
TwoPy = ((m.mul(baseXCoord.sub(TwoPx))).sub(baseYCoord)).mod(order);

console.log(TwoPx);
console.log(TwoPy);
console.log(isPointOnCurve(TwoPx, TwoPy));

// Helper Functions:
// Check if point is on Curve, Calculate extended GCD, modular inverse

function isPointOnCurve(x,y){
    b = ellipticCurveB;
    p = generatorPrime;
    rem = (y.pow(bigTwo).sub(x.pow(bigThree)).sub(b)).mod(p);
    return rem.eq(bigZero);
}

function egcd(a, b) {
    var s = BigNumber.from(0), t = BigNumber.from(1), u = BigNumber.from(1), v = BigNumber.from(0);
    while (!a.eq(BigNumber.from(0))) {
        var q = b.div(a) | BigNumber.from(0), r = b.mod(a);
        var m = s.sub(u.mul(q)), n = t.sub(v.mul(q));
        b = a;
        a = r;
        s = u;
        t = v;
        u = m;
        v = n;
    }
    return [b, s, t];
}

function mod(x, y) {
    return (x.mod(y).add(y)).mod(y);
}

function modinv(x, y) {
    var tuple = egcd(x.mod(y), y);
    if (!tuple[0].eq(BigNumber.from(1))) {
        return null;
    }
    return mod(tuple[1], y);
}
```

Comment: You are confusing the order of the group and the field where the curve is defined. The curve coordinates are defined in F_p where `p=FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFE FFFFFC2F` so you need to find inverses and execute the modular reduction of the coordinates according to the this modulus.

Comment: @kelalaka So I went into my code and changed the modulus to be p (what I called the primeGenerator), and it worked! Thanks! I will go update the post momentarily.  I am definitely confused, though. What is the group order used for other than determining the range of legal private keys? Anything in the calculation?

Comment: The group order is important for the [discrete log](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76230/18298). Consider that [a]G and [b]G are the pairs passing through during DHKE and you both side calculates [ab]G. ( [2]G is the doubling, [3]G is tripling, etc.) Then if attacker can solve Dlog than boom!

Comment: You can post your update code as an answer, at least I'll upvote. And make it more readable the m, twoPx and twoPy are not really easy to grasp, use intermediate variables...

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you very much!  You've been a great help, and I've learned quite a bit more than I expected.  I have posted my answer taking into account your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kelalaka pointed out in a comment on the original post, I was confusing the the order of the group and the finite field F<sub>p</sub>.  I was getting values modulo the Group Order, when I should've been using the values modulo prime p used to define the finite field.

The new and correct result I get is:

```
X: 0xc6047f9441ed7d6d3045406e95c07cd85c778e4b8cef3ca7abac09b95c709ee5
Y: 0x1ae168fea63dc339a3c58419466ceaeef7f632653266d0e1236431a950cfe52a
```

If anyone would like to use this code, I've updated it to be correct, and cleaned it up to make it a little more readable:

```
bigZero = BigNumber.from(0);
bigTwo = BigNumber.from(2);
bigThree = BigNumber.from(3);
ellipticCurveB = BigNumber.from(7);
generatorPrime =     BigNumber.from("0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F");
baseXCoord = BigNumber.from("0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798");
baseYCoord = BigNumber.from("0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8");

// slope = ( (3*x^2) * (2*y)^-1 ) mod order
threeXSquared = bigThree.mul(baseXCoord.pow(bigTwo));
modInv2y = modinv(bigTwo.mul(baseYCoord), generatorPrime);
m = threeXSquared.mul(modInv2y).mod(generatorPrime);

// 2Px = slope^2 - 2*baseXCoord
mSquared = m.pow(bigTwo);
twoXbase = bigTwo.mul(baseXCoord);
TwoPx = (mSquared.sub(twoXbase)).mod(generatorPrime);

// 2Py = slope * ( 2Px - baseXCoord ) - baseYCoord
pointSlopeX = m.mul(baseXCoord.sub(TwoPx)); 
TwoPy = (pointSlopeX).sub(baseYCoord).mod(generatorPrime);

console.log(TwoPx);
console.log(TwoPy);
console.log(isPointOnCurve(TwoPx, TwoPy));

// Helper Functions:
// Check if point is on Curve, Calculate extended GCD, modular inverse

function isPointOnCurve(x,y){
    b = ellipticCurveB;
    p = generatorPrime;
    rem = (y.pow(bigTwo).sub(x.pow(bigThree)).sub(b)).mod(p);
    return rem.eq(bigZero);
}

function egcd(a, b) {
    var s = BigNumber.from(0), t = BigNumber.from(1), u = BigNumber.from(1), v = BigNumber.from(0);
    while (!a.eq(BigNumber.from(0))) {
        var q = b.div(a) | BigNumber.from(0), r = b.mod(a);
        var m = s.sub(u.mul(q)), n = t.sub(v.mul(q));
        b = a;
        a = r;
        s = u;
        t = v;
        u = m;
        v = n;
    }
    return [b, s, t];
}

function modulus(x, y) {
    return (x.mod(y).add(y)).mod(y);
}

function modinv(x, y) {
    var tuple = egcd(x.mod(y), y);
    if (!tuple[0].eq(BigNumber.from(1))) {
        return null;
    }
    return modulus(tuple[1], y);
}
```

Comment: You see the code as more readable and manageable. This should be the first step before thinking about performance/security. Have fun!